# PHP Unit terminal UI not aligned/filled with whitespace

Tags: php, terminal, phpunit

When I run phpunit in any terminal windows (integrated with VS code, standalone, etc) I get this problem where it doesn't neatly align the stack trace:

[image: whitespace problem]

It seems to be adding a lot of whitespace. I have had a Google to see if anyone has encountered this & maybe I'm wording it wrongly but I can't find much info about people experiencing this same issue.

Does anyone have any advice how I can get it aligned like:

```
│ /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:115
│ /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:84
```

Comment: I have never seen output like that unless a custom result printer was involved.

Comment: Oh crap, that's not good news

Comment: There is little information given in the question, so guessing here:  Something that modifies stacktraces to make logging "easier"? Perhaps some "good intention" tooling within the Laravel setup? But again, just guessing. Reset the configuration, then downgrade it to the very bare minimum and see which component introduces the issue (configuration: everything from your IDE tooling down to the code). In the end you might provide the best feedback (over everyone else).